# How to change the domain of URL without changing query parameters using Requestly?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, redirection, web, requestly

My first use case would be to change the domain of a URL without changing the rest of the parameters using [Requestly](https://www.requestly.in).

Specifically change from

```
https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=123&text=Hi
```

To

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=123&text=Hi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can change the domain (or in loose terms any part of the URL like host, params, path or infact any substring of URL) using [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) Replace Rule.

There are two ways using which you can achieve this use case.

### Example 1

> Replace web.whatsapp.com
> With api.whatsapp.com
> URL Contains

[image: Replace Rule Example]

**Note** - This rule will just replace `web.whatsapp.com` with `api.whatsapp.com` irrespective of where `web.whatsapp.com` comes in URL.

So if your URL is, https://example.com?utm_source=web.whatsapp.com the rule will do the replacement as well.

### Example 2

> Replace web.whatsapp.com With api.whatsapp.com
>
> Host Contains web.whatsapp.com

[image: Replace Rule Example 2]

**Note** - Setting up a rule like this gives applies more control over when the rule should be applied. It will only replace web.whatsapp.com with api.whatsapp.com when web.whatsapp.com comes in the host.

Here's official documentation of Replace Rule - https://www.requestly.in/blog/2018/06/16/replace-rule-documentation/